# Problemas para hacer el login en Android Studio utilizando Ionic

Tags: android, angular, ionic

He creado un proyecto en Ionic, tengo por un lado la BD MySQL, el servidor en el cual hago las peticiones rest  y el login en ionic ( haciendo las peticiones a mi servidor para poder hacer la validación del login).

Cuando lo ejecuto, funciona perfectamente en la web, se hace el Login y me lleva a otra página donde tengo información.

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto en Android Studio me da error, aparece como que nunca se llega a realiza la consulta a mi servidor y la aplicación cae.
No sé por qué funciona en web y en Android Studio no

He intentado cambiar de:
http://localhost:3000/login';
a:
http://ip:3000/login';

pero me sigue sin funcionar, alguien me podría orientar, no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Y la *ip* que has puesto, es accesible desde la máquina virtual de android studio? Debes tener en cuenta que cuando ejecutas código en android studio es como si estuvieses utilizando un *dispositivo externo*, con lo cual `localhost` haría referencia a dicho dispositivo, y no a tu servidor. Debes usar la IP de tu servidor, pero asegurarte de que es accesible!

Comment: He creado otro proyectos utilizando mi ip y nunca me ha dado error, asi que "supongo" que si será accesible, pero no estoy del todo segura, donde puedo ver o verificarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Me pasó y acabo de solucionarlo, tuve que ir al archivo:

> 'network_security_config'

Que se me creó automáticamente, el cual apuntaba a **'localhost'** y cambiarlo por la IP donde estaban mis servicios, espero te sirva

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).